# Aligning HTML Input Fields in a Row

Tags: html

I want to align delete row and cancel buttons so that they appear on screen in a single row.

```
<table>
<td colspan="7">
<form action="<?php echo appurl('administration); ?>" onsubmit="return delRowsExtra()"   method="post" name="del">
    <input type="hidden" id="selectedDel" name="selectedDel"/>
    <input type="hidden" id ="degr" name="degr" value="<?php echo $t['degree']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="bat" name="bat"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="sec" name="sec"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="sem" name="sem"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="accTy" name="accTy"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Row" style="margin-left:125px"/>
</form>
</td>
<td>
<form action="<?php echo appurl('administration'); ?>" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" name="mainPage">
    <br/><input type="submit" value="Cancel" style="margin-left:150px" />
</form>
</td>
</table>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JMudE/

Comment: try float left in css, and when floating must define width and height. It is required for some design. Or try display property in css as table for input fields and then float left. Also check which browser it is.

Answer (score 0):

Add classes to your forms and use CSS aligning. Your best best is to try `.class{ display: inline; }` which will make the form an inline rather than block (extra line breaks) element.

http://w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp
http://w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: I want to align without CSS.

Comment: Can I ask your reasoning for avoiding CSS? I see that you're using the "style" attribute. If you don't want an external or header stylesheet, just append the style there. <form ... style="display:inline;">. You could also try encompassing both of your <td>'s in a <tr> tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you just want to align the delete and cancel button.

http://jsfiddle.net/JMudE/1/

Why not just `valign="bottom"`? You can add it in either a CSS class, in the `<table>` tag or the `<td>` tag.

Comment: I want to align without CSS.

Comment: No problems :) happy to help

Answer (score 0):

There is a

```
<br />
```

before the right button. It does the line break.
Remove it to align your buttons.

Also, you say that you want to align without CSS, but you are already using inline CSS — margin-left, for example.

Comment: Yeah,I am sorry. Actually, I meant I can use inline CSS, only. Thanks!